# Use of tifffile for analysis of 16 bit color TIFF images

Tags: python, image

This is not so much a question as a warning. I have been starting to do some analysis of 16 bit TIFF images. In preliminary testing I generated a 3x3 pixel image with different color pixels (R,G,B,C,M,Y,K,white,gray). Using `a=tifffile.imread(filename)` gives me a numpy array with shape (3,3,3) and dtype uint16, as I expected. However, when I do `tifffile.imwrite(filename1,a)` I get a different image. I tried it on a 4x4 pixel image (R,G,B,white) and got the same problem. A 6x6 pixel image works fine.

So tifffile.imwrite does not appear to work well on pathologically small images. But it's always good to note limitations in modules.

This is not really a problem for me since the images I want to use are much larger than these test images.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by `"I get a different image"`. Tifffile passes the roundtrip of a 3x3x3 uint16 numpy array so it works consistently in that case. The options to format the TIFF differently are documented `help(tifffile.TiffWriter.write)`. E.g. if your original TIFF is using separate planes to store the pixel components, use `planarconfig="separate"' to rewrite the TIFF. The numpy array does not carry this information.

Comment: IMHO this is a) not a question and b) not very fair on the developer of `tifffile` without showing code that demonstrates your case and without raising an issue with the developer.

Comment: I recognize it's not a question but I made that clear in the first sentence. I just thought people should know about a limitation I found.

Test image was a flat 9 pixel image.

Comment: Code is:
~Python
        a=tiff.imread(f)
        print(a.shape)
        print(a)
        print(a.dtype)
        tiff.imwrite(f1,a)
~

In looking at the printout of the array it appears that the problem I see may be in imread rather than imwrite

Comment: Tried to format the code but it didn't format properly and I ran out of the 5 minute edit time.

Note that I only found the problem with a 3x3 pixel image. I doubt that there are many of this type of images out there that are interesting. I only used it to try to understand the way the module works.

Images (screensaver of expanded images) at https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/dleilx1a3pczpqevaij06/h?dl=0&rlkey=oozj2ug49csd1zho5v1faqm95

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce the issue. The following code passes:

```
import numpy
from tifffile import imread, imwrite
from matplotlib import pyplot

# interleaved/contiguous color components
a = numpy.array(
    [[[65534, 65534, 65534], [65534, 0, 0], [32766, 32766, 32766]],
     [[65534, 0, 65534], [0, 65534, 0], [0, 65534, 65534]],
     [[65534, 65534, 0], [0, 0, 65534], [0, 0, 0]]],
    dtype=numpy.uint16
)

imwrite('test.tif', a)
b = imread('test.tif')
numpy.testing.assert_array_equal(a, b)

pyplot.imshow(b >> 8)
pyplot.show()
```

[image]

If the color components in the image are instead stored as separate planes, use the `planarconfig` argument to write the image:

```
# planar/separate color components
a = numpy.moveaxis(a, -1, 0)

imwrite('test.tif', a, planarconfig='separate')
b = imread('test.tif')
numpy.testing.assert_array_equal(a, b)
```

Comment: Upon further investigation I find the problem appears to be outside Python. I had generated the initial image file using Photoshop. I looked at the numbers produced by imread and the colors were not numerically pure. I tried it with several different configurations of the write from Photoshop and saw no difference. Generating the image within Python does work. Not sure just why at the moment, but will investigate further. It doesn't appear to be a problem with the color space.